# Not getting instance of services in custom library in angular6

Tags: angular, service, shared-libraries

I am new to Angular6, using custom library feature. I have created two libraries one for shared-services and other for shared component. In shared component, i am not able to use shared services.

```
 //shared-service
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { ScrollToService } from './scrollTo/scroll-to.service';
import { LoaderService } from './loader/loader.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
 ],
declarations: [],
//providers: [ScrollToService, LoaderService],
// exports: [ScrollToService, LoaderService]

})
export class SharedServicesModule {
 static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
 return {
  ngModule: SharedServicesModule,
  providers: [ScrollToService, LoaderService]
    }
  }
}


***************
 //shared-library module
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { SharedServicesModule } from '@shared-services';


 @NgModule({
  imports: [
  CommonModule,
  SharedServicesModule.forRoot()
 ],
 declarations: [],
 exports: [

    ]
  })
  export class SharedLibraryModule { }

//component in shared-library
  import { LoaderService, LoaderState } from "@shared-services";
```

here LoaderService not found.

Error:
    error TS6059: File '/Users/b0206580/Projects/cocp-admin-ui/projects/shared-services/src/lib/loader/loader.service.ts' is not under 'rootDir' /Users/b0206580/Projects/projects/shared-library/src'. 'rootDir' is expected to contain all source files.

Comment: `SharedServicesModule` should have `providers: [ScrollToService, LoaderService]` option

Comment: it is still showing same error.

Comment: issue is fixed now. there is some changes in my tsconfig.

Answer (score 0):

Your tsconfig.json should have the following,

```
  "paths": {
      "@shared-services": [
        "dist/@shared-services"
      ]
    }
```